# I need to create a tiktok video Downloader

Tags: python, download, download-manager, tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm trying to create a tiktok downloader,
So i'm trying to download videos from the video id ,

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer >>>"))
R = print(f"https://api16-normal-useast5.us.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/aweme/detail/?aweme_id={x}")
```

i use this code to combine the tiktok Video Id with url that give us the data with tiktok account picture,the audio,and the link the can download the video without the watermark

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api16-normal-useast5.us.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/aweme/detail/?aweme_id=7165099726885457178")
 # bytes
print(r.text)
```

and i use this code to get the data from the url that i create from the first code,
these two codes are separate codes i need to combine these codes with one code

so basically i want after i enter the Tiktok video ID and The data about the video ,like the url that can download the video
appear in my terminal

if someone can , help me

i try searching on google but i can't found any solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you print the URL and then copy and paste it manually to the second code?